# How to establish fully gpu-accelerated session to localhost xen virtual machine via RDP or VNC?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, xen

**Done so far:** I have setup xen-hypervisor on LinuxMint and successfully passed through my secondary GPU HD6850 to virtual machine running windows 7 Ultimate. The card is successfully recognized from virtual machine and all drivers are setup.

**The problem:** I don't want to use separate dedicated keyboard,mouse,display to work with the virtual machine. I would prefer to connect to virtual machine via RDP or VNC or any other client but as far as I have tried they do not provide high frame rates so not able to stream HD video which is essential to get work in my case.

**Note:** The connection is not needed to work over network. The RDP or VNC client would be run from the same physical HOST where xen server and virtual machine (windows 7) are located so there should not by any extra network traffic.

Host (xen-hypervisor-4.1):
-cpu: intel i7 3770 @3.4GHz (VT-D enabled)
-os: LinuxMint 14
-gpu(for host): HD7970
-gpu(for VM): HD6850

VM:
-os: windows 7 Ultimate
-gpu: Radeon HD6850 (passthrough card)

Answer (score 1):

VNC or RDP will not give you fully-accelerated graphics performance.  Citrix does better with HDX on their ICA protocol, but even that is not native performance and has some limitations.

If you want to run the VM with a separate KVM, you'll need to get primary graphics pass-through working, then you'll also want to use a PCI(e) USB device and pass that through for hooking up a keyboard and mouse.  Info on PCI and graphics passthrough, including tested devices for primary graphics passthrough, is available on the Xen wiki at xen.org.